# How to obtain and compare neighboring point attributes? (ArcInfo)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, point, fields-attributes

This question is kind of hard to explain in a short phrase, so this is what I'm talking about. I have access to an ArcInfo 10 license.

I have a layer of point features that all have a "Team" attribute that corresponds to a favorite sports team. I would like to define some search radius and, around each point, search for the most common "Team" value in the search radius. Essentially, for each point, I want to determine what the most popular team is in a given search radius. I have over 10,000 points, so this would have to be something fairly automated. My end goal is to turn a bunch of points into some kind of "blob map" that defines regions where a particular sports team is most popular.

I was initially thinking of creating a buffer of desired radius around each point and then spatially joining the attributes of the points to buffer polygons. At that point I'd do some fancy work in Excel or something to determine the most numerous "Team" value, but that doesn't feel like the best way to go. Any help or partial ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Point_Density/009z0000000v000000/.